# trigger after on insert, error table mutation upon inserting record

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, relational-database, sqlplus

I have created a trigger that will update the `Payment` table (for bill) when a new record is inserted to the table `Enrollment`. My trigger is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EnrollFee_trig
AFTER INSERT ON Enrollment
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
amount Payment.TotalPrice%TYPE;
id Payment.LearnerID%TYPE;

BEGIN
SELECT SUM(Price) into amount
FROM LearnerEnrollCourse_View
WHERE LearnerID = :NEW.LearnerID
AND Paid = 'N';

SELECT LearnerID into id
FROM Payment
WHERE LearnerID = :NEW.LearnerID
AND PaymentDate IS NULL;

IF SQL%FOUND THEN
UPDATE Payment 
SET TotalPrice = amount 
WHERE LearnerID = :new.LearnerID
    AND PaymentDate IS NULL;
ELSE  
INSERT INTO Payment VALUES
     (PaymentID_Seq.nextval, :new.LearnerID, '', amount);  
END IF;

END;
/
```

The trigger can be created successfully. But when inserting new record into `Enrollment` table, there is error saying ' table `ENROLLMENT` is mutating, trigger/function may not see it'. I want to know more specific about what problem causing this and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutating table exceptions occur when we try to reference the triggering table in a query from within row-level trigger code. See more [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions.php)

In this instance I suspect ( though I don't know as there is no definition for LearnerEnrollCourse_View ) the problem is caused by this statement :-

```
SELECT SUM(Price) into amount
FROM LearnerEnrollCourse_View
WHERE LearnerID = :NEW.LearnerID
AND Paid = 'N';
```

If the LearnerEnrollCourse_view view refers to the Enrollment table, you will get the mutating table error. There are a number of ways round it, moving your trigger code into a statement level trigger and holding the data in package variables is one workaround, in general though, I think using triggers is not the best way to do this, the more triggers you have, the more likely you are to run into this and other problems. Instead, I would have an api package for the enrollment table, and move the trigger code into there.

Good discussion of triggers [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)

Comment: yes, the view does refer to the `Enrollment` table. In statement level trigger, how can I get the newly inserted column data such as :NEW.LearnerID?

Comment: You can use package variables to store the data in the row trigger, then refer to the package variables in the statement level trigger. However, it isn't something I'd advise doing.